# When to use more Activities

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I have an Activity which is an OpenGL view.  I also have an xml layout to use for preferences.  Until now, to show the preference menu, I just brought it to front by setContentView().  And the same to get back to the OpenGL view.

But is this a case where I should give the preference menu its own Activity?

I guess this would make a few things much easier.  For example, the back button would just work, opposed to now where I have to code it or it will just exits the application.

And if this is a good idea, how do I pass data both ways?  I have a class that store all preferences.  Can I send it to the Activity and back again?  Or is the best way to store the preferences in a sqlite database and then use it for passing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to segregate menus and such into separate activities (unless you are using dialogs etc..) As far as storing data you can do it a number of ways:

1. Database
2. StoredPreferences
3. Intent extras with putExtra/Bundle
4. Creating an application subclass and storing preferences there

Each have their merit. 4 is pretty easy as you just have to state the application class name in your manifest then call: MyAppClass app = (MyAppClass)getApplicationContext(); and you can then use any variables in MyAppClass via app. 2 is also straightforward.

Comment: I think 3. is the only viable option. One should not use global storage to pass data between Activities.

Comment: Thanx! I think I'll go for number 2.  I don't only need to pass data between Activities, but also store them between sessions.

Comment: @Peter Kengo 4 is as well. For a game it makes sense to have an application subclass that can be instantiated from Android. It handles this natively so it would be faster than a bundle/intent extras. Most of the time the Game objects are complex so breaking them down into natives is not always an option especially since a game can contain a ton of relevant variables that may be needed in sub-activities.

Answer (score 1):

You already pointed out the main difference: history management.

You can pass data to Activity via Intents putExtra()/getExtra():

1. Create an Intend and add custom data via `Intent.putExtra(..)`
2. Start the new Activity: [`startActivityForResult(intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).
3. Inside new Activity you can get extra data with `intent.getXyzExtra()` (where xyz is type).
4. When new Activity is done just call [`setResult(int, resultIntent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29). Again you can add extra data as described in 1.
5. Call `finish()` to end the activity.
6. In original Activity method [`onActivityResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) will be called. Again extract data from Intent as described in 3.